# Implementing Applicative#apply with `map2`

Tags: scala

Looking at `Applicative#apply` in [Functional Programming in Scala](http://www.manning.com/bjarnason/), I'm getting a compile-time error on the `apply` function:

```
 C:\...\Applicative.scala:28: A does not take parameters
                              map2(fa, fab)(_(_))
```

Here's the code from the book:

```
trait Applicative[F[_]] extends Functor[F] {
  // primitive combinators
  def map2[A,B,C](fa: F[A], fb: F[B])(f: (A,B) => C): F[C]

  [code omitted]

  def apply[A,B](fab: F[A => B])(fa: F[A]): F[B] =
    map2(fa, fab)(_(_))
```

Why is this compile-time error occurring?

Answer (score 0):

With apply you want to apply the A => B function to an A in the computation context of F.

map2 lets you think inside F, while combinating two Fs into one.

```
def map2[X,Y,Z](fx: F[X], fy: F[Y])(g: (X,Y) => Z): F[Z]
```

You have to provide the two Fs, and a function g which combines what is inside.

So lets think inside F with apply:

```
X is a function with type A => B
Y is the argument with type A
   and with g we combines these by applying A => B  to  A, so 
Z is the result with type A)
```

When you provide g in the form `_ (_)`
you are saying, that you want to apply g's first argument, to g's second argument. If you write `map2(fa, fab)`, the first argument of g will be `a: A`, and the second `ab: A => B`. It will not type check because `a(ab)` is incorrect, what you want is `ab(a)`.

**TL;DR** swap the two arguments, fa, and fab

```
def apply[A,B](fab: F[A => B])(fa: F[A]): F[B] =
  map2(fab, fa)(_(_))
```

Comment: What's a verbose way of writing `(_(_))`?

Comment: `(f, x) => f(x)` -https://github.com/pchiusano/fpinscala/blob/7b962343a977d59e63d315b9622ac060203f643b/answerkey/applicative/2.answer.scala